# Error building project while excluding transitive dependency in build.gradle file

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, build.gradle

I am creating a multi module project with Spring Boot for deploying my application and using gradle as my build tool.

Now, I am creating independent deployments for some modules in the project. Some of the project requires Embedded tomcat and some do not. All the common dependencies have been put on a common project and all other modules are dependent on this common project.

Most of the other deployment modules require an embedded tomcat application server and other web components (provided by org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web) so this has been included in the build.gradle for common project

Here is the build.gradle for common project:

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: springBootVersion
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator', version: springBootVersion
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: springBootVersion
compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-jpa', version: springDataJpaVersion
```

Now, one of the other modules which is going to be deployed independently does not require this embedded tomcat and other mvc jars which comes with including spring-boot-starter-web but requires the other transitive dependencies from common project. As such, I want to exclude the transitive dependency for

```
 compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: springBootVersion
```

I am doing it like this in the build.gradle other project

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':common') {
        exclude group 'org.springframework.boot', module:'spring-boot-starter-web'
    }
}
```

But while building it is throwing this error:

> startup failed:   build file
>   '/Users/user1/Documents/repo/storm/build.gradle': 30: expecting '}',
>   found ',' @ line 30, column 44.
>        oup 'org.springframework.boot', module:'

changing it to:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':common'){
        exclude group 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    }
}
```

throws:

> Could not find method exclude() for arguments [parent-project name] on
>   project ':common'.

How can I exclude transitive dependency here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to invoke `exclude` on `compile` not on `project`:

```
dependencies {
   compile(project(':common')) {
       exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module:'spring-boot-starter-web'
   }
}
```

Comment: What does it mean _didn't work_? It fails or dependencies are not excluded?

Comment: Sorry for not being explicit . It failed to compile  and i got error as

Could not find method exclude() for arguments [parent-project name] on project ':common'.

However , When I changed the build file and did below :

configurations {
 compile.exclude module: 'org.springframework.boot'
 compile.exclude group :  'spring-boot-starter-web'
}

The project compiled but still When I run my application , it starts an embedded tomcat . I dont want embedded tomcat to start and my application to run over tomcat ? Any ideas how to do this .

Comment: Ah yes.. There's not `exclude` method on `project` instance. Have you tried: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923516/how-do-you-exclude-a-transitive-project-dependency-in-gradle ?

Comment: Opal , I think setting transitive = false will exclude all dependencies of subproject whereas I only want specific dependencies to be excluded (importantly , I dont want tomcat to be started :(  and my application to be deployed on it ).

Comment: I'm not sure if you can exclude project dependencies partially :/

Comment: Could you please verify my edited answer? I mean invoking `exclude` on `compile` object not `project`. Does it work?

Comment: yes Opal , your modified answer worked . But Still I see tomcat is getting initialized :(  .

Comment: If it worked, please accept it. I guess that problem with tomcat is a different problem for another question. Do You have a sample project that reproduces the problem?